# Fundamental group of an open subscheme of a normal scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible normal projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $U$ be the open subscheme of smooth points of $X$. Consider the closed subscheme $Z = X \setminus U$. Suppose that the codimension of $Z$ in $X$ is at least $2$. Is it true that the fundamental group of $U$ and $X$ are isomorphic?

Edit: Is it true for $X$ an integral normal projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: In codimension $2$, is it not a cone over an elliptic curve a counterexample?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi  Is cone over an elliptic curve reduced? (sorry for asking a stupid question). Actually, I want to know the result for X normal projective integral scheme over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Of course it is reduced

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me expand my comment into an answer.

Take as $X$ the cone of vertex $v$ over an elliptic curve $E$. Then $X$ is simply connected (this is a general property of projective cones). However, $U = X-\{v\}$ is *not* simply connected: in fact, the projection $\pi \colon U \to E$ onto the basis gives $X$ the structure of a topological fibration with fiber homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, so the corresponding long exact sequence of homotopy groups yields $$\pi_1(U) = \pi_1(E) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Am I mistaken or is the fiber homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$? (not that it makes a difference for the conclusion).

Comment: @cgodfrey: yes, thanks. I will correct it

Answer (score 4):

In fact, quite the opposite tends to be true. Mumford [1] showed that for $(X,0)$ the germ of a normal surface singularity (over $\mathbf{C}$), $U=X\setminus 0$, one has $\pi_1(U)=\{1\}$ if and only if $X$ is smooth. At the same time, $\pi_1(X) = \{1\}$ since $0\to X$ is a homotopy equivalence.

If $X$ is smooth, this is true (the etale variant is called "Zariski-Nagata purity").

**EDIT.** To address Francesco's comment: of course the example is not projective. The easiest projective example was given by Francesco in his comment: $X$ is the (projective) cone over an elliptic curve $E$ and $U$ the complement of the vertex. Then $\pi_1(U)= \pi_1(E) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\pi_1(X) = \{1\}$.

[1] *Mumford, D.*, [**The topology of normal singularities of an algebraic surface and a criterion for simplicity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02698717), Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 9, 5-22 (1961). [ZBL0108.16801](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0108.16801).

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, $X$ is not projective in your example.

Answer (score 4):

Although $X$ and $U$ need not have isomorphic fundamental group (as the accepted answer shows), the induced map from the inclusion $U\hookrightarrow X$ is generally $\pi_1$-surjective.

Precisely, if $X$ is a normal projective variety, and $A\subset X$ is a proper closed subvariety, then the natural homomorphism $\pi_1(X-A) \to \pi_1(X)$ is surjective.

You can find this result in [*On the fundamental groups of normal varieties* by Donu Arapura, Alexandru Dimca, Richard Hain.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1483)

Interestingly, although natural inclusions only give $\pi_1$-surjections, it turns out that natural projections do give $\pi_1$-isomorphisms.

Precisely, let $G$ be a connected reductive algebraic affine group over an algebraically closed field $k$ (arbitrary characteristic).  Assume $G$ is acting on a smooth connected projective variety $M$ (and there is an appropriate ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$).  Then the homomorphism (induced by the GIT projection) of algebraic fundamental groups $\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(M/\! /_{\mathcal{L}}G)$ is an isomorphism.  If $k = \mathbb{C}$, then there is also an isomorphism between the topological fundamental groups.

You can find this result in [*Fundamental group of a geometric invariant theoretic quotient* by Indranil Biswas, Amit Hogadi, A. J. Parameswaran](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5156).